# how to implement drag and drop to upload files in django, while i have already implemented simple file upload

Tags: django

I have below code for upload file but i need to implement drag and drop functionality on top of that in django please help with my code.

upload.html

```
{% block content %}
  <div method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="myfile"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">

{% endblock %}

Views.py

def simple_upload(request):
    # return HttpResponse("<H2>Upload</H2>")
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location="ciscotest/uploadedmedia")
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,"fileupload":"File uploaded successfully"})
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add *class="dropzone"* to your form.  See this answer for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654196/2606766